# Copy-Paste In Python

Tags: python-3.x, clipboard

I am new to python. So I wanted to improve my skills. Before posting this question I tried to find some code or an idea that would guide me with what I intend to do. I did see some examples and posts on SO and other sites. But they all(the ones I came across) showed how to do it for single object. Below is what I want to do.

I want to write a utility in python that would allow me to choose from content I want to paste based on what my last 10,say, copy commands were for.
suppose I clicked copy when selecting a folder and then later I selected some text and pressed ctrl+c. Now I want to get option that would let me paste both the folder as well as the text. 
Is that possible?

Thanks.

Comment: The module pyperclip manages the clipboard in python. Why did you not find this yourself? I just googled "python clipboard."

Comment: I Did go through posts on SO too. But I was not sure how to do it for multiple copies on clipboard.
I will take a look at your search terms.
Thanks

Comment: It's important to post your research effort on SO. Say you looked at it, how far you got etc., otherwise your question is likely to be closed and/or downvoted.

Comment: I will take care of that in future.
Thanks

Comment: Well, you have downvotes now. If you improve this question I'll change mine at least and it might get more attention. As it stands -3 DV tells a lot of would-be answerers to not bother, so you may want to improve it by editing.

Comment: Done. And It is now -4 DV :(

Answer (score 1):

You could save the last 10 text items from a clipboard using tkinter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import Tk
from collections import deque

def call_repeatedly(root, delay, func, *args):
    func(*args)
    root.after(delay, call_repeatedly, root, delay, func, *args)

def poll_clipboard(root, items):
    text = root.clipboard_get()
    if not items or items[-1] != text:
        items.append(text)

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw() # hide GUI
    clipboard_items = deque(maxlen=10) # save last 10 clipboard items
    call_repeatedly(root, 50, poll_clipboard, root, clipboard_items) # ms
    call_repeatedly(root, 1000, print, clipboard_items) # print every second
    root.after(10000, root.destroy) # exit in 10 seconds
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

It polls clipboard every 50 ms. Polling is bad in general if there is an alternative interface that could allow you to subscribe to the clipboard events to be notified when new item is copied into the clipboard.

> will it work for any kind of content, text, images etc. ?

This code works with text only. In general, you could get/set other types e.g., images (gtk, qt might provide a cross-platform way to do it).

> Will it allow me to copy-paste text across all the applications ?

You are working with a clipboard so yes, it should work across all applications that can 
work with a clipboard.

> Can we make it work as normal ctrl+c (copy command)

Copy command can be implemented using a `set` command e.g., [from `pyperclip.py`](http://coffeeghost.net/src/pyperclip.py):

```
def gtkSetClipboard(text):
    cb = gtk.Clipboard()
    cb.set_text(text)
    cb.store()
```

`gtkSetClipboard(text)` copies `text` to the clipboard.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Sorry for being too naive here. I have few questions.
Will it work for any kind of content, text, images etc. ? 
Will it allow me to copy-paste text across all the applications ?
Can we make it work as normal ctrl+c (copy command)? 
Sorry if that is too basic to ask.

Thanks Again.